# Bash quoting within command substitution

Tags: bash

I am having a hard time understanding this.
The following command expand files:

```
% echo "(echo " * " )"
(echo  foo.txt bar.txt  )
```

But this doesnt

```
% echo "$(echo " * " )"
 *
```

Asterisk * is unquoted. Shouldn't the file globbing happen for both cases? How does command substitution affect this case?

Comment: It's inaccurate to say that the second one has the asterisk unquoted. `$()` opens a new quoting context -- thus, quotes only start in that scenario when you open them. By contrast, with `()`, there's no new context opened.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think this is the answer, please put it as so :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's helpful to look at the commands individually.

```
% echo "(echo " * " )"
```

...has only a single quoting context. Here, `( echo` is quoted, an `*` is given unquoted, and then a `)` is given quoted.

---

```
% echo "$(echo " * " )"
```

Here, you're performing a command substitution, with the inner command having its own quoting context. Specifically, that inner command is:

```
# the inner command for the substitution is run first
echo " * "
```

...which emits `*` as its output, as one would expect. Notably, because it has its own quoting context, content starts unquoted, and only becomes quoted when the `"`s are seen.

Then, the substitution is performed; *because the `$()` is inside quotes*, that substitution process does not run string-splitting and glob expansion (which, if these steps were followed, would break the output of the inner command into multiple words, and expand each word as a glob).

```
echo "$(echo "*")"
```

...thus becomes...

```
# effectively single-quoted because we already finished running expansions
# so expansions that would be allowed in double-quotes are already finished
echo ' * '
```

---

By contrast, if you didn't quote:

```
echo $(echo "*")
```

...would become...

```
echo *
```

...which would have behavior in line with what you anticipated.

---

Or, the other way around

```
echo "$(echo *)"
```

...would become something akin to

```
echo 'foo.txt bar.txt'
```

Comment: I accepted this as this gives a more complete explanation.

Comment: Trouble with these is bash reference manual (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) doesn't detail any nesting cases. Also, although I have heard of this "command substitution have its own quoting context" in stackoverflow a couple of times, it is eerily missing in bash manual.

Comment: Bash follows the POSIX sh specification, and `$()` comes from there. If you want a canonical language reference, that's the way to head.

Comment: See section 2.2.3 in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html, and section 2.3 rule 5.

Comment: You are right. I am looking for language specification that could resolve ambiguous cases. 2.2.3 specifies exactly what I want to know. Thanks!

Comment: (...to pedant-proof my comment a bit: Bash is *almost* a superset of the POSIX sh specification; while typically extensions are placed in unspecified space, its `echo` implementation is noncompliant by default unless both `posix` and `xpg_echo` runtime options are enabled. However, a compliance bug at the parsing level would be a surprise).

Answer (score 2):

```
% echo "$(echo " * " )"
# --------|--------|
#produces |        |
#         echo " * "
```

Which is a quoted `*`.

Same for the outer `echo` you have shown, the output of cmd-substitution is quoted, you only see a `*`.

That is to say, what is inside the `$( .... )` is processed before the enclosing command is executed.

IHTH